# How to Train TensorFlow object detection model in Google Cloud?

Tags: python, cloud, tensorflow2.0

I have cloned the TensorFlow models repository and have labeled images, created TFRecord files, and created a label map, as mentioned on the TensorFlow documentation. I am having trouble understanding what to do to actually train the model. I do not have GPU, so I would like to train it in Google Cloud, or any cloud service? Can anyone explain this or provide a guide that simplifies the docs?

If it helps, I am using TensorFlow 2.2 with the aim of object tracking in an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Colaboratory (https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb) to code and train models from your google drive. It allows you to use free GPU/TPU for ML tasks.

You can also use Google Cloud Platform (GCP). When you create a new account you're given some free credits. You can create an Ubuntu VM instance as per your required configuration and use it to train your model.

Comment: Understood - do you know how exactly to use Google Cloud Platform to train a model. I am not sure what to upload or if I need to create new configuration files.

Comment: Please follow this link: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8pXhTmxZRA) to create a VM instance and install Ubuntu Desktop environment or your preferred OS like Windows if you have a valid license. You can then use it to install Anaconda and setup Tensorflow environment and train your model like you'd do on your PC.